# C++ Find Word in String without Regex

Tags: c++, string, find, cpu-word

I'm trying to find a certain word in a string, but find that word alone. For example, if I had a word bank:

```
789540132143
93
3
5434
```

I only want a match to be found for the value 3, as the other values do not match exactly. I used the normal string::find function, but that found matches for all four values in the word bank because they all *contain* 3.

There is no whitespace surrounding the values, and I am not allowed to use Regex. I'm looking for the fastest implementation of completing this task.

Comment: their has to be "whitespace" to separate it as a word... at least a line break.... find \n3\r or \n3\n

Comment: Are you counting linebreaks as whitespace?

Comment: Have you tried using stringstream?

Comment: Okay. I want to implement a function that is supposed to look at a file and decide how many of each word there are in that file, and I was doing that by putting all the words first into a vector, removing duplicates, then finding that word and counting the occurrences. Is there a better/faster way I can do this? I'll go take a look at stringstream.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the words you should use a string to int `map`. Read a word from your file using `>>` into a string then increment the map accordingly

```
string word;
map<string,int> count;
ifstream input("file.txt");
while (input.good()) {
    input >> word;
    count[word]++;
}
```

using `>>` has the benefit that you don't have to worry about whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

All depends on the definition of words: is it a string speparated from others with a whitespace ?  Or are other word separators (e.g. coma, dot, semicolon, colon, parenntheses...)  relevant as well ?

## How to parse for words without regex:

Here an accetable approach using [`find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and its variant [`find_first_of()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/):

```
string myline;     // line to be parsed
string what="3";   // string to be found
string separator=" \t\n,;.:()[]";  // string separators
while (getline(cin, myline)) {
    size_t nxt=0;
    while ( (nxt=myline.find(what, nxt)) != string::npos) {  // search occurences of what
        if (nxt==0||separator.find(myline[nxt-1])!=string::npos) { // if at befgin of a word
            size_t nsep=myline.find_first_of(separator,nxt+1);   // check if goes to end of wordd
            if ((nsep==string::npos && myline.length()-nxt==what.length()) || nsep-nxt==what.length()) {
                cout << "Line: "<<myline<<endl;    // bingo !!  
                cout << "from pos "<<nxt<<" to " << nsep << endl; 
            }
        }
        nxt++;  // ready for next occurence
    }
}
```

And here the [online demo](http://ideone.com/ma0zoF).

The principle is to check if the occurences found correspond to a word, i.e. are at the begin of a string or begin of a word (i.e. the previous char is a separator) and that it goes until the next separator (or end of line).

## How to solve your real problem:

You can have the fastest word search function:  if ou use it for solving your problem of counting words,  as you've explained in your comment, you'll waste a lot of efforts !

The best way to achieve this would certainly be to use a [`map<string, int>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) to store/updated a counter for each string encountered in the file.

You then just have to parse each line into words (you could use `find_fisrst_of()` as suggested above) and use the map:

```
 mymap[word]++;
```

Comment: Okay, so if I wanted to, for example, keep track of where I found each word, I could still use the function implemented above and then do whatever I need to do before I increment nxt?

Comment: Yes, exactly:  the `nxt++` is only here to ensure that the next iteration will start after the current occurence.    The two nested `if` ensure that the word matches exactly.  You can do whatever you want where the `cout` are